# Is it possible to place @click event in Template literal in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

```
 <button class="viewButton body" @click=${this.$router.push({ name: 'Staff Profile', params:{obj: JSON.stringify(sdList[s.staff_id-1])} })}>More Details ></button>
```

I have tried to put the @click event in a Template HTML by adding ${} to allow the click event to work. However, it does not work. May I know what other methods can I do?

Comment: You can't ans should not really do that. What is your endgame with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like so:

`@click=“$router.push({ name: 'Staff Profile', params:{  obj: JSON.stringify(sdList[s.staff_id-1])} })”`

Vue event handler syntax is `@click=“”`

You can listen to any DOM event, Vue docs on event handling: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html

Here’s DOm events wiki(little bit cleaner than mdn imo): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

Also, there is no `this` in template.

Comment: I am trying to add the @click event in a Template Literal
` `

Comment: @Apple What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @Apple Have you able to get it figured out?

Comment: @RussDeneychuk The above does not work --> @click=“$router.push({ name: 'Staff Profile', params:{  obj: JSON.stringify(sdList[s.staff_id-1])} })”